# Get Text from Button By getElementsById. But its not Working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

String ss = (String)jse.executeScript("var x=document.getElementsByName('submit')[0].value; return x");

System.out.println("Caption of Save button: " + ss);

I want to use the same code . ..but getElementById

Where i have to change. .in the above code??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using WebDriver's findElements instead of using JavascriptExecutor?
The statement below should work:

```
String ss = driver.findElements(By.id("submit")).getText();
```

Also, do you need to look for multiple elements by id? The id should be unique, so findElement maybe more appropriate than findElements.

Comment: Yes . .It Works :D
But Need to use .findElement not findElements !